# Ubuntu 20.04 download for iMac G5 PowerPC

Tags: 20.04, powerpc

I am trying to find a working web page from which I can download an ISO file for the latest version (20.04) which I can install on a powerPC platform (ImacG5).

Comment: Isnt Ubuntu website working?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know ubuntu doesn't support PowerPC architecture in the newer releases anymore(To be precise , from **Trusty Tahr** or **14.04** onwards).However you can download the older versions like 14.04 but that's not maintained in the [ubuntu official download repository](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/trusty/release/) anymore.So you have to use the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/).

Fortunately I was able to find a working download link for you that was saved in Aug 2015 (If fact it's **Lubuntu** which has a lighter desktop environment and is more conservative in memory usage) :

https://web.archive.org/web/20160825231011/http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/trusty/release/lubuntu-14.04-alternate-powerpc.iso

**But there is also an alternative** : You can use [Debian for PowerPC](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/ppc64el/iso-cd/) if you want to have a newer kernel and more up-to-date and secure packages in your pocket because the PowerPC architecture is supported officially by the Debian group.

But note that despite of the advantages that a newer OS has , it can be quite difficult to run a new OS smoothly in your iMac because the hardware is rather old. Looks like you have **512 MB of 533 MHz PC2-4200 DDR2 SDRAM
Expandable to 2.5 GB** in your iMac G5 according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMac_G5#Revision_history).See [Debian hardware requirements](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/powerpc/ch02.html.en).

For more information see [this guide](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO).

---

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:** Ubuntu has PPC port as well but it's unofficial and is maintained by the community.It's very difficult to find the download links for it.I don't know why.But at least I found a [Ubuntu Server 20.04 for POWER architecture](https://ubuntu.com/download/server/power) but not PowerPC and I don't think you can run it in your iMac.

For more information see [this announement](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2007-February/000098.html) and this [FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ)

Comment: Thanks guys. Yup, a very old machine, albeit with max ram and an ssd. Only opens some ISOs, none successfully so far, but will try your suggestions.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/powerpc/index.html The Power Architecture ISO will work as its for ppc64el. It's a server version install. I too am looking for the desktop version.

Comment: You can download it here http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.6/release/ There's only the server (CLI) edition, but you can install lubuntu-desktop afterwards.

Comment: @LewisEmery Finally, did you find an ISO that works?