# iMac G5 - anything 64-bit?

Tags: lubuntu, 64-bit, mac, powerpc, ppc64le

I'm helping a friend refurbish an iMac G5. So far I've got Lubuntu 16.04 LTS running on it, which is great, but I'm wondering if I can do better.

The machine DOES have a 64-bit PowerPC processor, but I can't figure out if it's possible to run the ppc64el (little-endian) on this machine for which there IS more support, and I can't find anything that's not "el".

I'm guessing no, since this is a POWER4 (PPC970) and not a POWER8.

EDIT: Apparently Fedora 25 would work, but I'm not sure if that would gain me anything over 16.04 LTS...

Any thoughts?
R

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 download for iMac G5 PowerPC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252195/ubuntu-20-04-download-for-imac-g5-powerpc) - Also check out server images: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/20.04.1/release/

Answer (score 0):

You're right, a G5 cannot run ppc64le binaries.

You can absolutely run more recent ppc64 big-endian binaries, but Ubuntu won't supply them to you. You'd need to look for another, more specialised distro. These days if I need to build something for ppc64 big-endian I would probably use [`buildroot`](https://buildroot.org/), but you might want something more user-friendly like [Adélie Linux](https://www.adelielinux.org). There's also a kinda-sorta supported [Debian ppc64 big-endian project](https://wiki.debian.org/PPC64).

Just be aware that support for ppc64 is going away or has gone away for some projects, like [Go](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/34850) or [OpenMPI](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/4349).